# Spring boot API which accepts JSON (mandatory) and multipart file (optional)

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to create an API which accepts both object (as JSON) and allows to upload multiple files.

- Uploading file is optional. i.e. a request may or may not have one or more files in request.

I am using spring boot at tried code below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some-action", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void post(@RequestPart(value = "jsonString") String jsonAsString, 
                 @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile[] files, 
                 HttpServletResponse response)
```

I am accepting `jsonAsString` because I was not able to accept object instead. So, for temporary solution I am passing json string.

Now, as you can see in code above that for `file` I have set `required` to `false`. But, I am getting server error when I am not passing any file.

Below is my request body.

```
--ARCFormBoundaryer1k80a5e1att9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

"{"key":"value"}"
--ARCFormBoundaryer1k80a5e1att9--
```

Below is error I am getting.

`org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.readHeaders(MultipartStream.java:487) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:889) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:854) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2730) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]`

Please suggest me what can I do to fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. We tried something similar. Unfortunately because of the different way file uploads get handled than normal data payloads on a POST, you will probably have to use a different URL.

We got it working in one browser (can't remember which), but it was flakey. It's kind of like overloading a URL.

Sorry, but I hope this does disappoint you too much...

Comment: Don't we have any other optional like we can have filter which tries to read multipart data and then put a `File` instances in request corresponding to received file? Finally, we will have only Files in request at Controller.